# I don't understand how to organise my fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have realised an NFC reader application

So i have 3 activities :

MainActivity, which is an activity who contains a Button. If button is clicked, the scan is activated and the user can put his NFC tag against the device to detect it.

WebActivity, who is launched if the NFC tag contains and URL (and open a WebView) or if the user want to launch WebActivity by himself

HistoryActivity, who gonna contains a list of every scans.

Now, I would like to swipe activity with a finger gesture. according to my research on Internet. I need fragments and ViewPager.

But every example that I saw is bases on ONE activity and multiple fragments.

But in my case, I have to create 3 fragments (one per activity), right ?

And I really don't know how to manage my fragment. I mean, what to put inside ?

All I want to do is create a transition/animation while changing activity... That's crazy

Comment: You just have to stop using Activities for something that should have already been a Fragment. You only need 1 Activity and 3 Fragments.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand ? Thanks for your response. You mean I need to make just an MainActivity, and put my History, Webview (and potential  other features) into differents fragments ?

Comment: Yes, 1 Activity to host fragments, and everything else is each a fragment. In fact, you probably want 1 Activity, 1 Fragment in it to host the ViewPager, and then the 3 Fragments you can swipe between are child fragments of that one fragment with the viewpager. See https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/c643f03a023a9cbe83fff6c75c948d3b

Comment: Ok, so I call all my fragments in my activity_main.xml ?

Comment: You add a fragment to the Activity, where the fragment has a ViewPager, and you give the ViewPager a PagerAdapter as defined in the gist I linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too broad of a question but hopefully my answer will steer you in right direction.

1. You should definitely go with single activity/multiple fragments model. Aside of recommendations by Google, you could use navigation components, deep linking much easier then without single activity.
2. Yes you should be using ViewPager for the purpose (and likely your implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter` as well) however I do not understand what kind of swiping will you be doing

Reading your setup, I would suggest to use bottom view with 2 items (good example is here https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample). 2nd one would show history, first one would offer a button that activates your action, and then displays fragment with your WebView.

As a side effect of such implementation, you'd be able to go back from 2nd bottom view item to whatever first one holds - by pressing system back button - which I think is nice touch.

UPDATE to "swiping takes place anytime. " comment:

You could have single activity, ViewPager with 2 fragments. First fragment would display a button, 2nd fragment would display a history. You could freely swipe between them, as you want to. However to me it does not make sense to put WebView screen into this. WebView screen is result of action (NFC detection) and it should probably display as full screen, without any chance of swiping between main/history and itself. Hope it helps or I'm missing some important piece of info you did not share.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! Okay so I gonna make only one activity with few fragments. What I want to to is that : https://www.programering.com/a/MTO5MjMwATY.html by without the buttons at the top

Comment: What is displayed under the link is done very easily with ViewPager and the adapter, however what do you expect to happen while you're navigating? You mentioned screen with button, screen with WebView, screen with History. Do you want to initiate NFC action by just swiping from 1st to 2nd? That would be weird.

Comment: no i want to initiate NFC when i'm clicking on the main button on MainActivity

Comment: ok that makes sense. so when swiping takes place? swiping between which screens?

Comment: swiping takes place anytime. MainActivity to HistoryActivity, HistoryActivity to MainActivity, MainActivity to WebActivity, WebActivity to MainActivity. At any moment. No constraint. Thanks for your patience

Comment: I've updated my answer with comment. Kind of feel I'm missing some important piece of info.

Comment: WebView is not automatically launched. It launchs if NFC tag contains url AND that the user click on "visit" (on the modal containing message who appears after a Scan), and it can be accessible without scan, in this case, the user will arrive on the webpage of my school. EDIT : The scan button is only on the MainActivity

Comment: So, one activity and three fragments ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, he said it should be swipeable. Why is there bottom navigation and navigation component involved, then?